# Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in function array_push

Tags: codeigniter

I want to collect multiple checkbox values to process, but I got this 
error = Fatal error: Cannot use object of type `stdClass` as array in this

```
line = foreach ($keluhan as $gejala) { 
    array_push($cf_array, $this->Maturan->get_nilai_cf($gejala, $penyakit['kode_penyakit']));
}
```

Comment: show your `get_nilai_cf` method also

Comment: as error very clear you are trying to push object to array.

Answer (score 0):

Is $panyakit an actual array that your trying to access or an object?

If it is an object try accessing it like this:

```
 $penyakit->kode_penyakit
```